# Android onActivityResult not called

Tags: android, android-activity

**Situation**
I start 2 Activities in onCreate of my `StartActivity`. First my `MainActivity` and second my `UnlockActivity`, both right after each other.

```
 private final static int REQUEST_UNLOCK = 13245;
 [...]  
 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(mainIntent);
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, UnlockActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_UNLOCK);
```

UnlockActivity prompts the user to enter a code and closes only if the correct code was entered. My MainActivity contains the rest of the app.

It is important to me, that the activity launching order stays the same. `MainActivity` does loading while `UnlockActivity` is up. Also, `UnlockActivity` is used to confirm user-actions app wide and can also show up on a background timer.

Here are their AndroidManifest entries:

```
<activity android:name=".main.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
<activity android:name=".unlock.UnlockActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

**Problem**
I need to set a flag in my SharedPrefs wether the app has been unlocked once or not. To do so I tried to use onActivityResult

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_UNLOCK && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // i set the flag to true here
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason `onActivityResult` is never being called. Why?

Comment: upload your **UnlockActivity** for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Check two things.

1. If you need to get data from onActivityResult in MainActivity. Then call start UnlockActivity from MainActivity
2. Did you call `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)` and `finish();` in UnlockActivity?

Comment: Yes, Both is the case. I make sure to call startActivityForResult from the instnace of my MainActivity and not the fragment and in UnlockActivity i have a method finishWithResult(int) that basically calls setResult and then finish.